# Normal terminal can't read file but debugger terminal can

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run my code with the PowerShell terminal for Python in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> OSError: Failed to read app.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

My code:

```
import os
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
import keyboard

import threading
from threading import current_thread
from threading import Thread

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue

from collections import namedtuple

mouse = Controller()
tim = 0.5
time.sleep(3)
ways = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
conf = 0.70

app = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('app.png' , confidence = (0.70))
print(app)

#pyautogui.move(100, 200)
```

The complete error message:

> [ WARN:0@1.130] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('APP.PNG'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c: \Users\mathi\OneDrive\Documents\programmation\python\en_cours\wakfu_daily\test.py", line 22, in 
> app = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('APP.PNG' , confidence = (0.70))
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 172, in wrapper
> return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 204, in locateCenterOnScreen
> return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 420, in locateCenterOnScreen
> coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 378, in locateOnScreen
> retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 356, in locate
> points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 205, in _locateAll_opencv
> needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
>
> File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 167, in _load_cv2
> raise IOError(
> OSError: Failed to read APP.PNG because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

But when I run this code with:

- the debugger terminal of Visual Studio
- IDLE Python Terminal
- windows terminal

The code works perfectly.

Is this a problem of the extension, of the terminal, of the configuration or an other problem?

Comment: "not sure but i think it's windows command prompt" ??  Please explain!

Comment: what is the workspace you have opened and what is your file structure, never call your programs/scripts `test`

Comment: Not sure, but try to move all of your code files and assets from `one-drive` to local storage